# Widget aspect ratio 1:1 (square)

Tags: android, android-layout, widget, android-linearlayout

I need to make widget aspect ratio 1:1 - more precisely it has to be square.

My layout looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/rounded_conners" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent_color"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/btn03_off" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I'm changing the shape of the ImageView programmatically so it has to be ImageView. In the background is shape background and on the top of that is ImageButton.

I was trying to make my own SquareLayout extended from LinearLayout, but it seems that Android widget shows only LinearLayout and not his extended version where I overridden onMeasure(meethod)

```
public class SqueareLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
public SqueareLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SqueareLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}


@Override public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int size = width > height ? height : width;
    setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
}
```

}

Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: `int size = Math.min(width, height);` for prettier code.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It was just testing version :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that I finally solved my problem..

In my layout I'm using only one ImageButton:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_color"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/btn03_off" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And when I want to change my background shape (not src image resouce, which is on the top) I just call:

```
views.setInt(R.id.button, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.rounded_conners);
```

So the widget has the same aspect ratio as the image has.